# Android SQLite ModernAsyncTask #1

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-sqlite

I've built my database schema and gone on to specify my methods to query, update, add, and remove entries from the db, however upon starting the app I get a ModernAsyncTask error. I read about this in the android documentation but could not figure out how to implement the AsyncTask so as to minimize memory leaks. My log says the exception is occurring during doInBackground() Does anyone have any clue as to what may be going wrong here? I would love to confirm that I can add data to the database, query it, update it, and even remove it!

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";
public static final String COLUMN_BLURB = "blurb";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,
                   CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);

}
    @Override
    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME
                + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PHONE + " INTEGER,"
                + COLUMN_STATUS + " TEXT," + COLUMN_BLURB
                + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
public void addContact(ContactsDb contacts) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, contacts.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, contacts.getPhone());
    values.put(COLUMN_STATUS, contacts.getStatus());
    values.put(COLUMN_BLURB, contacts.getBlurb());


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public ContactsDb findContact(String name) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " =  \"" + name + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    ContactsDb contacts = new ContactsDb();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        contacts.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contacts.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        contacts.setPhone(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        contacts.setStatus(cursor.getString(3));
        contacts.setBlurb(cursor.getString(4));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        contacts = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return contacts;
}

public void updateContact(ContactsDb contacts) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_STATUS, contacts.getStatus());
    values.put(COLUMN_BLURB, contacts.getBlurb());
// Which row to update, based on the ID

    String selection = COLUMN_ID + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(contacts.getID()) };

    int count = db.update(
            TABLE_CONTACTS,
            values,
            selection,
            selectionArgs);
    db.close();
}

public boolean deleteContact(String name) {

    boolean result = false;

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " =  \"" + name + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    ContactsDb contacts = new ContactsDb();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contacts.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contacts.getID()) });
        cursor.close();
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}


}
```

Cheers and thanks for your time!!

```
04-29 05:48:39.390    7446-7465/treehouse.greenlight E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
Process: treehouse.greenlight, PID: 7446
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:418)
        at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
        at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:35)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:242)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
04-29 05:48:39.410    7446-7446/treehouse.greenlight E/ViewRootImpl﹕ mIsPenSupport: :false

Comment: post your AsyncTask code and logcat

Comment: I don't have any AsyncTask code -- like I was saying above I'm very confused on how to implement it.  I've included the log above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to be more specific in your question and show that your process sequence activity this error. This error is not the fault of the database, but beyond the capacity of your emulator or virtual machine. Anyway checks the configuration file and update Eclipse these values:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

Comment: it says `IllegalArgumentException` why it would be related to  memory size ?

Comment: Well I thought the idea was that the AsyncTask was causing a memory leak due to not being implemented in the database setup. Do I need to create a special class for that and if so how do I go about doing it / what should I keep in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Look, the error does not relate exactly to the database. Normally, errors of logic database, do not appear on android. The sample code you show is not what generates the error. Obviously you can control and manage your database based on the following criteria:
1. Know that there is a space reserved and inviolable Android placed your database.
2. When you build a derivative MyDBHandler, onCreate automatically runs.
3. If you include the creation of a table in onCreate, you must place ..getWritableDatabase, either in the constructor or in onCreate.
4. But know that when you use getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase, you must properly handle the SQLException, and your code does not.
5. It would be nice to be able to understand your logic, you hang around your project in your question.
regards